# mysql command freezing in windows console

Tags: mysql, windows, console, xampp

When xampp's MySQL is stopped. I am typing this in git bash console, I am receiving this error.

```
    $ mysql -v
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061 "Unknown error")
```

And when it is on, console just freezing. Don't know what to do. Xammp installation is fresh and MySQL added to the PATH. Previously all commands works in ubuntu, there was no problem at all.

Comment: What does the mysql error log say, when you started mysql? Any hints there?

Comment: Do not find anything helpful there. 
[Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.

Comment: What does `mysql -v -v -v` return? Does `mysql -h 127.0.0.1` work?

Comment: All this commands just freezing, nothing happening.

Comment: Check the task manager, please. Does the bash command window / the mysql process(es) draw any CPU memory or are they just idling? What happens, if you press CTRL-C on the hanging console? Does it come back?

Comment: Started 5 consoles and typed mysql -v  and mysqld.exe did not draw more that it was.

Comment: What about `mysql.exe` (not `mysqld.exe`) itself? What about CTRL-C?

Comment: Sorry, yes it created a new thread with 1,4 mb. After ctr+c its deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git bash doing the same thing to me. Powershell is working better.

Answer (score 1):

Needs to be `mysql -V` (capital V)